# How to pass data from a fragment Activity to a non activity class in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

Code 1  is a part of ***my Fragment class***
  From Code 1 ***i am getting my place name***. I want to pass that place name to a non Activity class That is to ***CODE 2***.

**Code 1**

```
@Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

            Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.ENGLISH);

            myAddress=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gpsLocation);
            surveyView = (SurveyView) getView().findViewById(R.id.surveyView);
            newsHomeView = (NewsHomeView) getView().findViewById(R.id.newsHomeView);
            audioView = (AudioItemView) getView().findViewById(R.id.audioView);

            AudioListener listener = (AudioListener)getActivity();
            audioView.setListener(listener);

            newsHomeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MainActivity mnAct = (MainActivity)HomeFragment.this.getActivity();
                    mnAct.moveToPage(Constants.NEWS_PAGE);
                }
            });

            iPrevIndex = -1;


            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                try {

                  //Place your latitude and longitude
                //  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(37.423247,-122.085469, 1);
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);
                  if(addresses != null) {

                      Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                      StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();

                      for(int i=0; i<=fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                            strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                      }
                    Log.i("country name ",fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex()));

                    String s=fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex()-1);// Bangalore, Karnataka, 560038
                    String str[]=s.split(" ");// array of Bangalore, Karnataka, 560038
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str)); // print all array element



                    //  myAddress.setText("You'r location is: " +strAddress.toString());

                  }

                  else
                      myAddress.setText("No location found..!");
                 // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please switch on yor gps",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Could not get address..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
```

***CODE 2***

```
    public class Audios extends BaseCollection<Audio> {


     private static String newValue;

     public static setNewValue(String value) {
            this.newValue = value;
            //Code to use this value.

        }
    @Override
    public void loadWithJson(JSONArray jsonObj) {



        if(null == jsonObj) {
            return;
        }
        try {

            List<Audio> entries = new ArrayList<Audio>();
            for (int o = 0; o < jsonObj.length(); ++o) {
                Audio opt = Audio.fromJson(jsonObj.getJSONObject(o));
             //  String title = opt.getTitle();
             //System.out.println(opt.getTitle().substring(0, 4)); // title.substring(0, 3);
        //          entries.add(opt);
                        entries.add(opt);   

            }
            this.entries = entries;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getAudioResult(JSONObject jsonRes) {
        int id, grpId, dwnCount, upCount;
        if(null != jsonRes) {
            try {
                id      = jsonRes.getInt(Constants.MEDIA_ID);
                grpId   = jsonRes.getInt(Constants.GROUP_ID);
                dwnCount= jsonRes.getInt(Constants.SET_THUMBS_DWN);
                upCount = jsonRes.getInt(Constants.SET_THUMBS_UP);
            }
            catch(JSONException je) { id = grpId = dwnCount = upCount = -1;}
            if(-1 == id || -1 == grpId) {
                return;
            }
            for(int iLoop = 0; iLoop < entries.size(); iLoop++) {
                Audio opt   = entries.get(iLoop);
                if(opt.token == id && opt.groupId == grpId) {
                    opt.thumbDwns   = dwnCount;
                    opt.thumbUps    = upCount;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }




}
```

In code 1 Hear i am getting my place name

Values:

```
place=str[1].substring(0, 4);
            AudiosFragment hm=new AudiosFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("place", str[1].substring(0, 4));
```

Please tell me how i will pass this **place** value.

Answer (score 1):

easy way to pass data from one class to another is by using constructor

Consider Example:

```
Class A{
Object o;
private methodA()        
{
B b = new B(o);       //here you are passing o to Class B
b.methodB();
}
} 

Class B{
Object o;
public B(Object O)
{
this.o=o;
}

public methodB()
{
use object o here
}
}
```

may be this will help..

Comment: Can you please explain this with respect to my classes i have given ?

Comment: add constructor `public Audios(String s) {this.newValue=s}` in your Audios class and in my fragment class create object like `Audios audios=new Audios([pass string here]);` then you can call `audios.loadWithJson(jsonObj);` etc methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Singleton class but is maybe to complex for only a String [].

```
public class Singleton {
  private static Singleton uniqInstance;
  private String str[];
  private Singleton() {

  }

  public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
    if (uInstance == null) {
      uInstance = new Singleton();
    }
    return uInstance;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i ll use this in activity one and activity 2 in my case Code 1 and Code 2

Comment: When you have done the Singleton class. Using getinstance in each activity setting and getting like an "local object". Take a look at this gist : https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992

Comment: In your example you are passing a constant string value.In my case its going to change every time. How that will work???

Comment: Is not constant… if you put in the activity1 Singleton.setStr(String str[]) in the activity2 or whereever getting an instance you are going to have access to this String [] with the values that you have been asigned and vice versa.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method inside the Audios Class.

Now, depending on the fact that you want different objects of the Audio Class to have different value for this String, you can define it static or not. Then just call that method.

Example :

```
Class Audios extends BaseCollection<Audio> {
    private static String newValue;

    public static void setNewValue(String value) {
        this.newValue = value;
        //Code to use this value.
        ..
    }
}
```

From the Fragment, just call `Audios.setNewValue("This is the value for the String");`

Comment: what change i have to make in fragment ??

Comment: You dont have to make any changes in the fragment. Whenever you want to update the value from the Fragment, just call `Audios.setNewValue("This is the value for the String");`

Comment: This is not working man. Could you  please check both the codes and tell me ..??

Comment: Can you post your updated Audios Class ? The one that is not working.

Comment: That's correct so what happens when you call Audios.setNewValue("New String") from your Fragment ?

Comment: Whenever you call this method, the value will just get updated. You'll then have to work on that value explicitly.

Comment: hear only its giving error . setNewValue(String value) is giving error. Its asking me to set the method type to void or make it a constructor . And  this.newValue = value; says cant use this static context .

Comment: no ... this.newValue = value; is giving error .. and please tell me how it will fetch the string from that fragment class??

Comment: yes worked...add constructor public Audios(String s) {this.newValue=s} in your Audios class and in my fragment class create object like Audios audios=new Audios([pass string here]); then you can call audios.loadWithJson(jsonObj);